# Why can't we use a fill_value when reshaping a dataframe (array)?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([list("ABCDEFGHIJ")])
​
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
```

I got an error when trying to reshape the dataframe/array :

```
np.reshape(df, (-1, 3))
```

**ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 10 into shape (3)**

I'm expecting this array (or a dataframe with the same shape) :

```
array([['A', 'B', 'C'],
       ['D', 'E', 'F'],
       ['G', 'H', 'I'],
       ['J', nan, nan]], dtype=object)
```

Why NumPy can't guess the expected shape by completing the missing values with `nan`?

Comment: This question cannot be answered with any answer besides saying that's just how numpy was written. The shapes must be compatible for numpy's `reshape` to work.

Comment: All right. In this case, I'm open to any good alternatives.

Comment: Then you have a different question than what you asked.

Comment: `np.resize` can pad the input (or truncate it).  But it isn't as basic a operation as `reshape`.  In practice there are too many variations to make that fill a default option.  For example why use float `np.nan` with 'U1' strings dtype?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @hpaulj. The default fill value doesn't necessarily need to be `np.nan`.

Comment: Generally `pandas` has more tools to fill frames and deal with missing values.

Comment: how pandas is involted in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible solution, based on [`numpy.pad`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html), which inserts the needed `np.nan` into the array:

```
n = 3
s = df.shape[1]
m = s // n + 1*(s % n != 0)
np.pad(df.values.flatten(), (0, m*n - s), 
       mode='constant', constant_values=np.nan).reshape(m,n)
```

Explanation:

- `s // n` is the integer division of the length of the original array and the number of columns (after reshape).
- `s % n` gives the remainder of the division `s // n`. For instance, if `s = 9`, then `s // n` is equal to 3 and `s % n` equal to 0.
- However, if `s = 10`, `s // n` is equal to 3 and `s % n` equal to 1. Thus, `s % n != 0` is `True`. Consequently, `1*(s % n != 0)` is equal to 1, which makes `m = 3 + 1`.
- `(0, m*n - s)` means the number of `np.nan` to insert at the *left* of the array (0, in this case) and the number of `np.nan` to insert at the *right* of the array (`m*n - s`).

Output:

```
array([['A', 'B', 'C'],
       ['D', 'E', 'F'],
       ['G', 'H', 'I'],
       ['J', nan, nan]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: I'm impressed! But how did you came up with `m = s // n + 1*(s % n != 0)` and `(0, m*n - s)`. I will be grateful if you can explain in details those two.

Comment: Welcome, @VERBOSE! Please, see the explanation I have just added to answer. If something is still unclear, please let me know it and I will clarify it.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `divmod()`

```
df.set_axis(list(divmod(df.columns,3)),axis=1).stack(level=0).to_numpy()
```

or

```
n = 3
np.r_[df.to_numpy().ravel(),[np.NaN] * ((n * -(df.size//-n)) - df.size)].reshape(-1,n)
```

Output:

```
array([['A', 'B', 'C'],
       ['D', 'E', 'F'],
       ['G', 'H', 'I'],
       ['J', nan, nan]])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You made it look so easy with pandas.